# How to unhyperlink links programmatically?

Tags: android, string, hyperlink

I have a large body of text that includes web urls and emails. I created a SpannableString object and used Linkify class to set up hyperlinks for the web urls and emails. However, perceived phone numbers also get linked. So even though I have instances of 5-digit numbers such as "12345", this numeric sequence also are being linked. When clicked, a prompt comes up asking to call the number. Linkify thnks it is a phone number. How can I go back through and un-link specific text that I know should not be linked?

Here is how I have linked everything

```
final SpannableString s = new SpannableString(context.getText(R.string.message));
Linkify.addLinks(s, Linkify.WEB_URLS);
textView.setText(s);
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Generally speaking, find the positions that need to be unlinked, find the spans around those positions via `getSpans()`, and remove the spans via `removeSpan()` (methods on `SpannableString`).

Comment: So I should recursively go through the text and then removeSpan() around the text that I want to unlink? Can you provide a quick example, I will make it as answer. Thank you.

Comment: I don't know about the "recursively" part. I don't have a ready example of searching for text and then removing spans from that text. This sample app searches text and *adds* spans (plus removes any existing spans), which you might be able to adapt for your purposes: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/RichText/Search

Comment: Ok thank you. If you provide answer I will accept. I will look into the project you linked.

Comment: Well, I didn't really answer your question, so I'd prefer to stick with the comments.